# Error when decrypt message from blowfish/base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, blowfish

I'm trying to decrypt some message encrypted by FiSH plugin from mirc. The plugin use a blowfish encryption as mode ECB based on a key but first it encrypted the messages as code64 and then with blowfish ECB. The problem is when I try decrypt the message with blowfish after decode it from base64 get the same error always. "Data must be aligned to block boundary in ECB mode"

The des encrypted message is: "Probando un mensaje cifrado"

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from os import urandom
import base64

key = b"passw0rd"
text =b"+OK Tnkrh0sIoWb1oS1FT.RQop/.JPXNc.lclFO/gueZ4/ZwN1H0"



decode64 = base64.b64decode(text)


decrypt = Blowfish.new(key,Blowfish.MODE_ECB)

msg = decrypt.decrypt(decode64)

print(msg)

site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py", line 163, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Data must be aligned to block boundary in ECB mode")
ValueError: Data must be aligned to block boundary in ECB mode

WITH NON-STANDARD TABLE:

custom_a = "./0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
standard_a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'

DECODE_TRANS = str.maketrans(custom_a,standard_a)

key = b"passw0rd"
text ="Tnkrh0sIoWb1oS1FT.RQop/.JPXNc.lclFO/gueZ4/ZwN1H0"
decode64 = base64.b64decode(text.translate(DECODE_TRANS))
decrypt = Blowfish.new(key,Blowfish.MODE_ECB)

msg = decrypt.decrypt(decode64)

print(msg)
```

Comment: 1. Don't use Blowfish, it is not considered secure, use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard), even the creator of Blowfish uses AES. 2. Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: I need use Blowfish because is the method used by the people have on irc. I can't use other. I need implement the Blowfish plugin from irc on my python script.

Comment: In that post I did get the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303306/irc-blowfish-encryption-mode. Thansk everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious problems I see here. There may be more, but these will need to be dealt with first.

1. You need to remove the prefix `"+OK "` from the message before decrypting it. It's not part of the encrypted data.
2. The data transmitted by FiSH is not standard Base64. It uses [a nonstandard encoding table](https://github.com/flakes/mirc_fish_10/blob/f283b05f4ba5f2d67a3a056401a7e64c76e04ab4/fish_10/src/blowfish.cpp#L15) which you'll have to account for.

Comment: I did try to do a non-standard decode table but the resulte is the same. "Data must be aligned to block boundary in ECB mode"