# NodeJS irc and blowfish

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a bot connected to a irc.
I need to send encrypted message. The problem I don't find any lib capble of to do that on nodejs.
For example I need to encryp "test" like this :`+ok uw.eY/70GsN/`
"+ok" is added after and the key to encrypt "test" is "Somek3ys"

The problem is blowfish on irc, it use an other base64: "./0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
and like I said, I didn't find anything :(

So if anyone is capble to do that or know a lib somewhere, it would be great !

Comment: I am not sure what your issue is.. "+ok" is being added by who? Can you supply the code you are using to encrypt?

Comment: Based on this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303306/irc-blowfish-encryption-mode
If I want encrypt something I need to the mode "MODE_ECB". something like this :
`var Blowfish = require('xs-blowfish');
    key = "Somek3ys";
    bf = new Blowfish(key);
    encoding = bf.encrypt("test");
    // here I should use the specific base 64 to encode the result into "encoding"`
But I can't use something like this `Buffer.from(encoding).toString('base64')` because it's not using the proper base64. And also I'm not sure either to use the proper lib to "fish" a text.